# websocket not working on https server

Tags: php, https, websocket

I am using ubuntu server with apache

my apache config setting on virtual host

```
 ProxyPass "/" "wss://108.61.199.230:9000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "wss://108.61.199.230:9000/"
```

And i am get the websocket code from in this link

https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets

In http server it working fine i don't know why it is not working properly
that means the connection automatically closed i can't send any data on websocket

Is there any other option or package to get this functionality please give the reference link

Please give any solution for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: any errors? anything helpful at all? otherwise, my only advice, read through those posts https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets/issues/41

Comment: i tried with this link guidance but this error only occur "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable".
"mdrmdrmdr commented on Aug 15, 2016" i follow his comment and change the "run" function but same problem is there

Comment: That library doesn't support secure connections.

Comment: Any one know another library for this please give the reference url